# SSI package execution failed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

SSIS package execution failed with the following error message:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Protocol error in TDS stream". Code: 0xC0047038 Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC0202009.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().

At this step, SSIS package transfers data from one table to another table.
Please advise, how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the error

1. Go to Start--> All Programs--> Microsoft SQL Server 2008--> Configuration Tools --> SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Expand the node SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration
3. Right click on "Aliases" and then select "New Alias..."
4. Provide the IP address of the Source SQL server against the "Server" field and specify the Source server name against the "Alias Name" field.
5. Choose the protocol as "NamedPipes" and click OK